# Could someone explain please how the code works

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

There is some code:

```
def func
   def func
      1
   end
end
```

then I try the following in `irb`:

```
func
func.func
func
```

and get the result:

```
:func
1
1
```

Could anyone please explain what's going on? I kinda understand the first output but not the latter. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You define a method inside a method in a global scope. Method definition returns a symbol with it's name.

1. When you call `func` for the first time, it's redefined, by the inner `func`. That's why subsequent calls to `func` return `1`.
2. Method definition returns a symbol and you can call any globally-defined method on the symbol, that's why you can call `func.func`. Try to define other method and you'll be able to call it on any symbol:

```
def func
   def func
      1
   end
end
def a
  'a'
end
func.a
# 'a'
:asd.a
# 'a'
```

Comment: I'm trying to invoke `a` on `func` and it returns `private method 'a' called for :func:Symbol (NoMethodError)`, Ruby 2.6.1p33 [x86_64-darwin18].

Comment: please, paste what you're trying to do.

Comment: Exactly the same what's in your answer https://repl.it/@vnhnhm/PureBlaringSymbols (Ruby 2.5.5p157 this time, as well).

Comment: works for me on `ruby 2.5.1p57`. Try in a new console.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! one more question: why dont we have to specify `:func` as a symbol to call `func.func` or `func.a` (the way we do it with `:asd`)? because of the `self` ?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking about. Could you tell it another way?

Comment: oh sorry:)
what i mean is that
`Method definition returns a symbol and you can call any globally-defined method on the symbol, that's why you can call func.func`
my question is that  why we can call `func.func` instead of `:func.func` (skipping symbol sign `:`)

Comment: Tried with Ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18], same error.

Comment: I get the same error as Sebastian if I run it on repl.it or write it in a file and run the file. It does work the way mrzasa described it if I test it in IRB. It also works if I add the `public` keyword before `def a` which doesn't make any sense since it should be public already :)

Comment: Code snippet works fine for me in MRI Ruby 2.4.1 irb.

Comment: @sofi The point is if you define a method in the irb global namespace it's added to `Kernel` which is included by almost all Ruby objects. `1.a` would work, `:foo.a` works, `"foo".a` works by just defining the `a` method in the global namespace. When calling `foo.foo` you simply call `foo` on the return value of the first `foo` call.

Answer (score 4):

This is complicated. This really *shouldn't* work in Ruby, but it does.

`def func` at the top-level defines a global method. But how does that work in Ruby? It actually uses two hacks:

1. It adds the method to `Object` so that you can call it from anywhere (because `self` is always an `Object`)
2. It makes the method `private`, because the rule for private methods is that they can't have an "explicit receiver" i.e. you have to call them without putting an object and a dot before them. This is to prevent mistakes like if I think that a class `Foo` has its own `puts` method but it actually doesn't, `Foo.new.puts` will raise an error, rather than call the global `puts`.

So if your code were just

```
def func
  1
end

1.func
```

It would crash because you're trying to call a private method on the object `1`.

*But* here's where it gets weird. If you define a method inside another method, it defines a *normal* instance method as if it were not nested at all

```
class A
  def outer
    def inner
      3
    end
  end
end

x = A.new
y = A.new
x.outer
y.inner # calls the method defined by x
```

This wasn't really an intentional design in Ruby, but more of a fallback for a weird situation. The [lead designer](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11665#note-3) doesn't like that it's even possible

> ...the current behavior of nested method definition is useless. It should be made obsolete to open up the future possibility (I'd vote for warning).

Your code behaves so strangely because you're doing it at the top level where `self` is just an `Object`:

```
def func # normal private method in Object
  def func # adds a normal instance method to the current class i.e. Object
    1
  end
end

Object.private_methods.include?(:func) # true
func # returns :func, but also now re-defines func to be a normal method on Object
Object.private_methods.include?(:func) # false
func.func # same as 1.func, which is OK because it's not private
```